# Count up on a positive change, and down on a negative change

Tags: mysql, arrays, sql-server

I have a column that changes values.
I want to count by adding at each change up and subtracting at each change down.  Assuming `x[]` are my values, `Delta` is the sign of change in x's elements, and `y[]` is my  targeted results or counts.

We count up until the next delta -1 at which we start counting down, then we resume counting up when delta changes back to +1. In summary we add normally until we have a delta of -1 at that time we start subtracting, then resume adding up at the next +1 delta.

```
x:     1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,  3, 3, 4, 5, 5,  6,  5,  4, 4, 4,  3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  8
Delta: 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0,  1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1
y:     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  8,  7, 6, 5,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

The length of my array is in the millions of rows, and efficiency is important. Not sure if such operation should be done in `SQL` or whether I would be better off retrieving the data from the database and performing such calculation outside.

Comment: So you want as result 10? Or do you want the current value for every value in the table?

Comment: Yes that would be correct, 10 is what I wanted

Comment: I guess you have a primary key, otherwise there is no order.

Comment: Yes the array have to be ordered before performing this analysis.  Otherwise the analysis would be useless.

Comment: You are loosing me on your delta impact on the starting X and Y values... is it supposed to be a cumulative set?  and if coming from a database, what column would be the basis of the order-by clause.  Maybe offering a pseudo code of how you are computing the running total edited to your answer would help too.

Comment: when delta is 0 it means there is no change, so the last up or down stays in effect. example for the values 1,2,3,2,2,2,1 the count should be 1,2,3,2,1,0,1. If there was a way to change the zeros of delta to the last non-zero value we would get our answer by sum the resulting array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this query in SQL-Server, presuming a PK-column for the ordering:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.ID, t.Value, 
           LastValue = Prev.Value,
           Delta = CASE WHEN Prev.Value IS NULL 
                          OR t.Value > Prev.Value THEN 1
                        WHEN t.Value = Prev.Value THEN 0 
                        WHEN t.Value < Prev.Value THEN -1 END
    FROM dbo.TableName t
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t2.ID, t2.Value
                 FROM dbo.TableName t2
                 WHERE t2.ID < t.ID
                 ORDER BY t2.ID DESC) Prev
)
, Changes AS
(
    SELECT CTE.ID, CTE.Value, CTE.LastValue, CTE.Delta, 
           Change = CASE WHEN CTE.Delta <> 0 THEN CTE.Delta
                    ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 CTE2.Delta
                          FROM CTE CTE2
                          WHERE CTE2.ID < CTE.ID
                          AND  CTE2.Delta <> 0
                          ORDER BY CTE2.ID DESC) END
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT SUM(Change) FROM Changes c
```

The result is 9 as expected:

- [complete result set](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d09fe/48/0)
- [only Sum](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d09fe/49/0)

The `OUTER APPLY` links the current with the previous record, the previous record is the one with the highest ID < `current.ID`. It works similar to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

The main challenge was the sub-query in the last CTE. That is necessary to find the last delta that is `<> 0` to determine if the current delta is positive or negative.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `LAG` and `SUM` with `OVER` (Assuming you have SQL Server 2012 or above) like this.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID int identity(1,1), [x] int);

INSERT INTO @Table1([x])
VALUES (1),(3),(4),(4),(4),(5),(5),(3),(3),(4),(5),(5),(6),(5),(4),(4),(4),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);
```

**Query**

```
;WITH T1 as 
(
SELECT ID,x,ISNULL(LAG(x) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC),x - 1) as PrevVal
FROM @Table1
), T2 as 
(
SELECT ID,x,PrevVal,CASE WHEN x > PrevVal THEN 1 WHEN x < PrevVal THEN -1 ELSE 0 END as delta
FROM T1
)
SELECT ID,x,SUM(COALESCE(NULLIF(T2.delta,0),TI.delta,0))OVER(ORDER BY ID) as Ordered
FROM T2 OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 delta from T2 TI WHERE TI.ID < T2.ID AND TI.x = T2.x AND TI.delta <> 0 ORDER BY ID DESC) as TI
ORDER BY ID
```

**Output**

```
ID  x   Ordered
1   1   1
2   3   2
3   4   3
4   4   4
5   4   5
6   5   6
7   5   7
8   3   6
9   3   5
10  4   6
11  5   7
12  5   8
13  6   9
14  5   8
15  4   7
16  4   6
17  4   5
18  3   4
19  4   5
20  5   6
21  6   7
22  7   8
23  8   9
```

Comment: Presumes at least SQL-Server 2012

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have a question:  WE created T1 then T2 and TI but in each case we did what was done prior again meaning we select ID, x, created PrevVal for T1.  Then instead of creating a 4th field called delta we first created T2 by re-selecting the same fields again then created delta.  Could we have created delta as a 4th field of T1 by providing its definition just as we defined PrevVal? Are we being thus redundant making the code less efficient or do we have to do it this way?

Comment: We cannot use the alias for `LAG` (`PrevVal`) to create the 4th field `delta` in T1. Only way to do that would be to expand the `LAG` in all places where the alias is used. Something like this. `ID,x,ISNULL(LAG(x) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC),x - 1),CASE WHEN x > ISNULL(LAG(x) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC),x - 1) THEN 1 WHEN x < ISNULL(LAG(x) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC),x - 1) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END as delta`

Answer (score 0):

You use sql-server and mysql tag. If this can be done within SQL-Server you should have a look on the OVER-clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Assuming there's an ordering criteria it is possible to state a ROW-clause and use the value of a preceeding row. Many SQL-functions allow the usage of OVER.

You could define a computed column which does the calculation on insert...

Good luck!